# Xcode 4.5 - No crash log

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, crash

I am using **Xcode 4.5**, I am using `LLDB` (and I have also tried with `GDB`). I have enabled an 'All Exceptions' breakpoint. But I have no luck in getting any crash log / stack trace.

I am in the process of building an app, so as you can imagine I have crashes littered all over the place. I cannot fix them if there is no crash log.

**Note:** `There is no crash log on the device or simulator`

Thanks for help!

Comment: I face this problem when i remove any property from code but does not remove it's reference from control line outlet from textfield or action from button. so check for this.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand

Comment: suppose u have make a propert IBoutlet TextField *txt. now u remove that lines from .h and .m file but u have not remove it from ur .xib or from storyboard at that time I m facing this kind of problem

Comment: thats not my problem....

Comment: my problem is that there are crashes without any breakpoints, or crash logs.... but they do not come from broken outlet links

Comment: Have you tried setting a top-level exception handler and dumping the stack to log yourself?

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean...

Comment: You can create your own exception handler function and handle all top-level exceptions. In that handler you can log the stack and exception details.  You can also do this in a top-level signal handler, to catch SIGSEGV, SIGBUS and SIGFPE.

Comment: @trojanfoe how would I do that?